# How to get all of the Google Calendar extended properties for an event with Jquery FullCalender event.extendedProps

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

FullCalendar allows access to Google calendar's event extendedProperties.

[Event Parsing](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing)

I'm trying to access my Google Calandar extendedProperties per the API and FC documentation but i'm unable to determine the name/attribute to request.

Based on success with the location property, this is what I've tried for the extendedProperties:

```
//works
var location = 'at ' + info.event.extendedProps.location;
//does not  work
var pet = 'at ' + info.event.extendedProps.extendedProperties;

//I've tried
 info.event.extendedProps.petsAllowed   
 info.event.extendedProps.extendedProperties   
 info.event.extendedProps.extendedProperties.petsAllowed  
 info.event.extendedProps.extendedProperties[petsAllowed]    
 
 info.event.extendedProps.privateExtendedProperties 
 info.event.extendedProps.privateExtendedProperties.petsAllowed
 info.event.extendedProps.privateExtendedProperties[petsAllowed]
```

The returned Google Event object shows the value, so it should be accessible:

```
["extendedProperties"]=>
object(Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties)#608 (5) {
["private"]=>
 array(1) {
["petsAllowed"]=>
 string(3) "yes"
}
["shared"]=>
NULL
```

When adding events in Google, ExtendedProperties is an array.
There are multiple custom ExtendedProperties by name, so it seems you'd need to identify each like "petsAllowed", "hasShots", "hasTags" , "under80lbs"
..there are many more so I need to tell FullCal (info.event.extendedProps ) exactly which extendedProps I want...or return them all so I can filter whats needed.
[image]

Comment: Since `extendedProps` is a [plain object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), I think you should be able to view all properties if you log `info.event.extendedProps`. Have you tried that?

Comment: yup,(and thanks for the suggestion).. it shows location/description in the "extendedProps". ...Mine is petsAllowed, I have a feeling that this may be a private/shared issue.  ....However, in the Google object, "extendedProperties" is on the same level with "location"...that 'ep' object is an array beginning with "private" ..so if FullCal see "location" as a extentedProps, it seems it would see "existingProperties" on that same level  or next level as "private"  ...I know the answer will be simple, but I'm totally missing it.

Comment: sorry..the correct sentence:  so if FullCal sees "location" as a extentedProps in it's obj, it seems it would see Google's "extendedProperties" on that same level in its obj.  Example: extentedProps = "location,description,extendedProperties"

Comment: Could you share what the `extendedProps` object looks like?

Comment: Done, the image doesn't show matching attributes for set/get..but its the configuration used ...the console log is always  location/description

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug on the function **gcalItemToRawEventDef** on [this file](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/packages/google-calendar/src/main.ts) of the **google-calendar package**. It is missing a line that turn the whole content of **extendedProperties** accessible, including the "private" part:

```
   extendedProps: item.extendedProperties
```

On the [dist of fullcalendar](https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar@5.3.2/main.js) (current version is 5.3.2) you can correct it using this patch:

```
--- 5.3.2_main.js
+++ 5.3.2_main_with_full_extendedProperties.js
@@ -14166,7 +14166,8 @@
             end: item.end.dateTime || item.end.date,
             url: url,
             location: item.location,
-            description: item.description
+            description: item.description,
+            extendedProps: item.extendedProperties
         };
     }
     // Injects a string like "arg=value" into the querystring of a URL
```